# wp_enqueue_scripts is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I copied everything exactly like in WordPress Codex but I don't know what's wrong that it doesn't work. This is the portion from function.php.

What am I missing?

```
define('JS_PATH', get_template_directory_uri() . '/resources/js');

<?php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_and_register_my_scripts');
function enqueue_and_register_my_scripts() {
    /* Remove JQuery */
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );   
    /* wp_register_script('custom script name', 'source', 'is it dependent', 'version', 'place at the bottom of footer'); */
    wp_register_script('jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js', false, '1.11.0', FALSE);
    wp_register_script('bootstrap', JS_PATH . '/bootstrap.js', 'jquery', '1.0', FALSE);
    wp_register_script('datepicker', JS_PATH . '/datepicker.js', 'bootstrap', '1.0', FALSE);
    wp_register_script('application', JS_PATH . '/application.js', 'jquery', '1.0', FALSE);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');
    wp_enqueue_script('application');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, the problem was that I was not including `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` in my footer.php